# Kinesis - Random guid partition keys only using a subset of shards

Tags: amazon-kinesis

The problem I am trying to solve is a relatively even distribution of records across shards on a kinesis stream.

I keep finding documentation and answers to other questions saying that if you don't need data to come across a particular shard, you can use a random Guid as the partition key to evenly distribute load across shards.

However, I keep getting throttled by AWS, and even when I scale the shard count up to 40 to test, I am only getting records coming across 6 or 7 shards when using a random Guid for the partition key.

If I manually set the partition key to a value coinciding with a given shard I am able to force an even distribution, but I have a requirement to use a particular Guid to ensure related records are coming across the same shard consistently, and the AWS documentation seems to say this should work just fine.

Any ideas what might be the cause of the Guids only using a small percentage of the available shards?

Comment: Clarifying this statement: `particular Guid to ensure related records are coming across the same shard` <-- We should not expect uniform distribution if this is the case. Is the `Guid` truly random or is it a hash value based on the record?

Comment: The Guid we ultimately use is a randomly generated Guid. It's the id from our user relation, and we need to ensure all records for a given user come across the same shard.

To test it though, I have been generating new random guids for each record I write to the stream, and that's where I am still seeing the same behavior as using the "live" Guid, in that it only spreads load to a few of the available shards.